# Swift getting value inside Optional()

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

When I am getting a value back from an API that I am hitting, when I print the data it appears as

```
Optional((
  jknjknjkn
))
```

for example. I use a selector to run a method when the data is returned

```
func result(data: AnyObject){
   println(data["info"])
}
```

What is printed is the Optional thing above. How can I get the value without that Optional() thing wrapping it?

Here is the raw data if I just print data

```
<AppUser: 0x78ec5650, objectId: I6nxFSZx9h, localId: (null)> {
AppID =     (
    jknkjnjknkn
);
info =     (
    jknjknjkn
);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Swift, an optional is a variable that can either hold a value or `nil` (no value at all).  To get the value from it, you have to *unwrap* it with an exclamation point:

```
func result(data: AnyObject){
   println(data["info"]!)
}
```

Note that if `data["info"]` was `nil`, your app would crash with this error message:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping Optional value
```

If you are concerned that the expression might produce `nil`, you can use *optional binding*:

```
func result(data: AnyObject){
   if let info = data["info"] {    //info is now the unwrapped version of `data["info"]
        println(info)              //will only be executed if data["info"] is not nil
    }
}
```

Comment: When doing data["info"]! I still get Option(( value )) printed out

Comment: Weird.  Try a clean and rebuild.

Comment: Same thing.. this is the raw data I get back if I do a straight prinln of data

<AppUser: 0x78ec5650, objectId: I6nxFSZx9h, localId: (null)> {
    AppID =     (
        jknkjnjknkn
    );
    info =     (
        jknjknjkn
    );
}

Comment: Does optional binding produce the same result?

Comment: Yes they both still print that Optional(( value ))

Answer (score 0):

Disregard this, I am trying to use Parse in a swift project and their documentation has multiple ways to show the code. I just copied a different code block and now I am able to do what I need to do just fine.